# Formulate GSheets formula involving nested IFs

Tags: google-sheets, formula

I have created a Google spreadsheet for our small business which lists all the invoices. I have uploaded a simplified format in 
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zYrRxDm0ahsjWE8aNquz-shHuNY_Eifl3lXLhIBUeTE/edit?usp=sharing.

1.There can be 1-5 products per invoice.

2.The column G is the total of all the products in that invoice. I want to create a formula for this column.

Presently, my formula is very long and inefficient.
The column (G) calculates number of products with this formula:

```
=IF(B3<>"",IF(OFFSET(B3,1,0)="",IF(OFFSET(B3,2,0)="",if(OFFSET(B3,3,0)="",if(OFFSET(B3,4,0)="",if(OFFSET(B3,5,0)="",5,5),4),3),2),1),0)
```

Another column (H) sums up the product values with this: `=IF(G3>0,SUM(OFFSET(D3,0,0,G3,1)),"")`

Help me rework the G column formula which calculates the number of products. If there's any way I can consolidate G and H that would be great too.

Note: the (I) column is just an alternative to (H) column.

P.S. Please don't flag this as an opinion based question. This is purely a problem solving question.

Comment: Could a helper column be added?  Ie one that counts the number items per invoice? is there an option to put the invoice number in instead of blank cells?

Comment: Do you mean to manually enter the number of items per invoice? That will increase the work of entry operators and also will increase the possibility of mistake.
If you mean by formula, its already being done in column G.
Inserting invoice no.s in blank cells will not look good in printing or viewing.

Comment: one place to start would be ro reference the cells directly instead of using offset.  it should shorten up your  formula and make it more readable.

Comment: I chose offset because deleting a row was messing up the formulas.

Comment: in order to consolidate G and H into a one cell calculation, simply substitute the equation you have in G3 into the equation in H3 wherever the h3 equation refers to G3.  It will become very ugly to read but it will put it all I n one cell for you.

Comment: and if I understand your question correctly, you got something that is currently working for you and you are wondering if there is a cleaner, quicker, better way of achieving the same results?

Comment: Consolidation is second priority, first is to shorten up the formula.

Comment: Yes its working correctly as of now. But the formula is ugly workaround and there has to be a better way to do the same thing.

Comment: Ok, I did this with the use of a helper column.  You could hide this column so it does not print and does not display for aesthetic purposes.  In column K starting in row 3 I placed this formula so basically fill in the invoice numbers without a blank `=IF(A3<>"",A3,K2)`, Then in column L startin in row three I placed this formula which gives the same results as you G column `IF(COUNTIF($K$3:K3,K3)=1,COUNTIF(K:K,K3),0)1 if this works for you then I will place it as an answer

Comment: IF you are ok with using a hidden helper column you can skip displaying the count of items and jump straight to the solution for getting H by using the following formula `=IF(A3<>"",SUMPRODUCT(($K$3:$K$12=A3)*$D$3:$D$12),"")`

Comment: FYI your current formula for count is actually not working right.  You will notice that your count for invoice 4  is 5 when then number of items is actually 4.  The count for the last invoice with your method will always be 5 unless you put something ln the row below the list item of the last invoice.

Comment: Your solution is working correctly, though I am not able to understand the last column. You can answer the question with helpful comments.

Also, thank you for pointing out the mistake of last invoice.

Comment: Please don't tag Google Sheets questions as Excel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are ok with the option of a helper column off to the side or hidden, we can do the following.

In column K starting in row 3 I placed this formula:

```
=IF(A3<>"",A3,K2)
```

You can actually use whatever column suits you just remember to update the column references in subsequent formulas.  It generates a column of invoice numbers with no spaces which allows some other formulas to work much easier for us.

In column L startin in row 3 I placed this formula:

```
IF(COUNTIF($K$3:K3,K3)=1,COUNTIF(K:K,K3),0)
```

This gives the same results as column G.  The first part of the IF statement is checking to see if the invoice number is the first occurrence of the invoice number.  If it is count how many times the invoice number occurs, otherwise display 0.

Now if you want to skip counting how many items there are in an invoice you can use the sumproduct formula as follows:

```
=IF(A3<>"",SUMPRODUCT(($K$3:$K$12=A3)*$D$3:$D$12),"")
```

now to account for a variable sized list of invoices we will count the number of invoices and adjust our formula with an offset to return the appropriate ranges as follows:

```
=IF(A3<>"",SUMPRODUCT((OFFSET($K$3,0,0,COUNT(K:K),1)=A3)*OFFSET($D$3,0,0,COUNT(K:K),1)),"")
```

Since we are using COUNT(K:K) it is imperative that no numbers be entered in this column other than those generated by our formula.

This treats items inside the brackets as an array, without the formula itself being an array.  The whole thing is placed inside an IF statement so that empty cells are displayed instead of zeros in the rows that do not correspond to an invoice number in column A.

now if you want to understand how sumproduct works in this case, its basically generating a an array filled with 1 or 0 representing true or false and then multiplying it by an array of the same size that is filled with all your amounts. So anything multiplied by 0 is 0 and anything multiplied by 1 is amount.  The final step of sumproduct is to add up all the values.  So you will only get the sum of what ever is true or 1.

Comment: I just noticed I kind of cheated.  I set the range as $K$3:$K$12 this will need adjusting to account for variable amount of rows due to your invoices.  I will check if K:K will work... might need to use an offset with a column count. Let me get back to you with some alternatives to cover this...assuming that sumproduct works in google sheets.

Comment: Is it safe to assume that column D will only contain numbers except for the headers?

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to utilise VBA, you could use a User Defined Function. Insert this code into a new module and call it like you would a normal excel function:

```
Public Function InvoiceDetail(Invoice As Range, ReturnType As Integer)

Dim varCount As Long
Dim varSheet As Worksheet
Dim varInvoiceID As String
Dim varPartyName As String
Dim varInvoiceTotal As Double
Dim varInvoiceCount As Integer

Set varSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Invoice.Parent.Name)

If varSheet.Range("A" & Invoice.Row).Value <> "" Then

    varInvoiceID = varSheet.Range("A" & Invoice.Row).Value
    varPartyName = varSheet.Range("B" & Invoice.Row).Value

    For varCount = Invoice.Row To 1000000

        If varSheet.Range("D" & varCount).Value = "" Then

            Exit For

        End If

        If varInvoiceID = varSheet.Range("A" & varCount).Value And varPartyName = varSheet.Range("B" & varCount).Value Then

            varInvoiceTotal = varInvoiceTotal + varSheet.Range("D" & varCount).Value
            varInvoiceCount = varInvoiceCount + 1

        ElseIf varSheet.Range("A" & varCount).Value = "" And varSheet.Range("B" & varCount).Value = "" Then

            varInvoiceTotal = varInvoiceTotal + varSheet.Range("D" & varCount).Value
            varInvoiceCount = varInvoiceCount + 1

        Else

            Exit For

        End If

    Next

End If

Set varSheet = Nothing

Select Case ReturnType

    Case 1 '// Count Only

        InvoiceDetail = varInvoiceCount

    Case 2 '// Total Only

        InvoiceDetail = varInvoiceTotal

    Case 3 '// Total [Count]

        InvoiceDetail = varInvoiceTotal & " [" & varInvoiceCount & "]"

    Case Else

        InvoiceDetail = "Error"

End Select


End Function
```

This code obviously assumes that your Invoice ID is in Column A, your Party Name is in Column B, and your Amount is in Column D. I've implemented a few options for you too:

`=InvoiceDetail(A3,1)` returns the number of items on the invoice (as integer)

`=InvoiceDetail(A3,2)` returns the sum of items on the invoice (as double)

`=InvoiceDetail(A3,3)` returns both sum and [count] (as string)

Comment: I am on Google Sheets, I'll have to understand this vba program and convert it to Google script.

Comment: Ah, apologies, I assumed you just used google sheets as an example

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this with 2 arrayformulas.

Paste this formula in any corresponding cell, let it be `O3`:

```
=TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(JOIN("",ArrayFormula(REPT(FILTER(A3:A12,A3:A12>0)&"-",
len(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(JOIN(",",A3:A12)&",","\d+","-"),"-")))))),"-"))
```

And this formula in cell `P3`:

```
=ArrayFormula(if(A3:A>0,SUMIF(O3:O,O3:O,D3:D),""))
```

My [sample file](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1nwfauc22mPsTidA1Zo2ZeiOLnObb1k_g4iL_Sz5PjCg/edit?usp=sharing).

---

To make the first formula work with different ranges:

- replace `A3:A12` to `offset(A3,,,counta(C3:C))`

Comment: Thanks, but this formula is more complicated and long than mine.

Comment: This formula expands automatically, so you don't need to drag it down